# Trying to use the mattn/go-gtk in golang with Win8.1 64bit

Tags: go, go-gtk

Trying to use the mattn/go-gtk in golang, https://github.com/mattn/go-gtk/ on Win8.1 64bit. I use LiteIDE X to write code and build.

While build this test code http://mattn.github.io/go-gtk/ I got those errors in the output window:

```
c:/go/bin/go.exe build  [C:/GoProjects/src/gtk_test]
# github.com/mattn/go-gtk/pango
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libpango-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/pango-1.0.lib when searching for -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libpango-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/pango-1.0.lib when searching for -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\pango-1.0.lib when searching for -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgobject-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gobject-2.0.lib when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgobject-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gobject-2.0.lib when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\gobject-2.0.lib when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgmodule-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gmodule-2.0.lib when searching for -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgmodule-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gmodule-2.0.lib when searching for -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\gmodule-2.0.lib when searching for -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgthread-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gthread-2.0.lib when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgthread-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gthread-2.0.lib when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\gthread-2.0.lib when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libglib-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/glib-2.0.lib when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libglib-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/glib-2.0.lib when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\glib-2.0.lib when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libintl.dll.a when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/intl.lib when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libintl.dll.a when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/intl.lib when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\intl.lib when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lintl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
# github.com/mattn/go-gtk/glib
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgobject-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gobject-2.0.lib when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgobject-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gobject-2.0.lib when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\gobject-2.0.lib when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgthread-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gthread-2.0.lib when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgthread-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gthread-2.0.lib when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\gthread-2.0.lib when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libglib-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/glib-2.0.lib when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libglib-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/glib-2.0.lib when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\glib-2.0.lib when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libintl.dll.a when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/intl.lib when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libintl.dll.a when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/intl.lib when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\intl.lib when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lintl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
# github.com/mattn/go-gtk/gdk
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgdk-win32-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgdk-win32-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gdk-win32-2.0.lib when searching for -lgdk-win32-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgdk-win32-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgdk-win32-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gdk-win32-2.0.lib when searching for -lgdk-win32-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\gdk-win32-2.0.lib when searching for -lgdk-win32-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgdk-win32-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libpangowin32-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpangowin32-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/pangowin32-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangowin32-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libpangowin32-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpangowin32-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/pangowin32-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangowin32-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\pangowin32-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangowin32-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpangowin32-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpangocairo-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/pangocairo-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangocairo-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libpangocairo-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpangocairo-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/pangocairo-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangocairo-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\pangocairo-1.0.lib when searching for -lpangocairo-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpangocairo-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gdk_pixbuf-2.0.lib when searching for -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gdk_pixbuf-2.0.lib when searching for -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\gdk_pixbuf-2.0.lib when searching for -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libpango-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/pango-1.0.lib when searching for -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libpango-1.0.dll.a when searching for -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/pango-1.0.lib when searching for -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\pango-1.0.lib when searching for -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpango-1.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libcairo.dll.a when searching for -lcairo
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/cairo.lib when searching for -lcairo
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libcairo.dll.a when searching for -lcairo
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/cairo.lib when searching for -lcairo
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\cairo.lib when searching for -lcairo
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lcairo
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgmodule-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gmodule-2.0.lib when searching for -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgmodule-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gmodule-2.0.lib when searching for -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\gmodule-2.0.lib when searching for -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgmodule-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgobject-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gobject-2.0.lib when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgobject-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gobject-2.0.lib when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\gobject-2.0.lib when searching for -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgobject-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgthread-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gthread-2.0.lib when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libgthread-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/gthread-2.0.lib when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\gthread-2.0.lib when searching for -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgthread-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libglib-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/glib-2.0.lib when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libglib-2.0.dll.a when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/glib-2.0.lib when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\glib-2.0.lib when searching for -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lglib-2.0
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libintl.dll.a when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/intl.lib when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/libintl.dll.a when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib/intl.lib when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/GTK/lib\intl.lib when searching for -lintl
c:/tdm-gcc-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lintl
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Error: process exited with code 2.
```

I use gtk+-bundle_2.24.10-20120208_win32 should I use the gtk3? If yes 64 or 32 bit?
Does anyone has run go-gtk on windows 8.1 64bit? Step by step guide?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the GTK dll's being 32 bit while you are building a 64 bit binary. It looks like you have the right GTK version. You just need the 64 bit build of that version. I haven't developed on windows in years but I'm betting the win32 suffix on your download you mention indicates that it was a 32 bit library.

Your other option is to cross compile a 32 bit binary but 32 bit go has some GC issues so I would recommend going with a 64 bit GTK instead if you can.